# Robocopy gets "Access is denied" copying from 2nd Windows 10 even though File Explorer can copy ok

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I get "Access is denied" when my 1st windows 10 computer tries to copy files with Robocopy from my 2nd Win 10 computer.

However, I can copy the files using File Explorer from 2nd computer to 1st ok.

I tried adding my account to files of 2nd computer, and this appears as:

```
<my name> (<name of 2nd computer>)\<my name>
```

BACKGROUND DETAILS...
1st computer maps 2nd computer to drive O: on 1st computer without problem.  I can use file explorer on 1st computer to access all files on 1st computer.

But I have a batch .bat backup file that uses robocopy to copy files from 2nd computer to Q: on 1st computer, which is my mapped external hard disk.

When this batch attempts to copy files from O: (2nd computer) to Q: I get "Access is denied".

Comment: You need to either take ownership of the folder that contains the data you want to transfer or add your user to the ACL.  You are getting a permission error due to the fact, the user you are trying to access the data with, did not exist on the other installation.

Comment: You refer to the computers as 1st and 2nd. In the title the 2nd reads files that exist on the 1st; in the question body it's the other way round. To avoid confusion please make this consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that on 1st computer some of the files were encrypted.  Windows encryption has been a nightmare for me for 20 years.  It is so buggy.  I tried one last time a couple years ago, but Microsoft never fixed the bugs.

For this issue, I deleted the encrypted files from 1st computer, and then Robocopy worked ok copying files from 2nd computer to 1st.  I had first unencypted all the files on 2nd computer.